# How to limit zookeepers port range for incomming connections

Tags: apache-zookeeper

We are having a port conflict with two services on our platform. 
One of the services is listening to port 45454, and the other service, is a zookeeper server.

The problem appears when the service listening on port 45454, restarts and then zookeeper accepts a connection and uses the same tcp port 45454.

Is there a way to limit which ports zookeeper can use? Or should we just change the service that listens to port 45454 to another (lower) port?

I've looked around and tried to google a solution but so far I've failed miserably at finding a solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear a connection client > server, needs a listen port on the server and random ephemeral port on the client side. Accepting connection does not require an additional port.

Zookeeper listens (defaults) on the `2181` for the clients and on the `2888`, `3888` for internal communication, no conflict. The most possibly your zookeeper established connection to another node, locally using ephemeral port.

Ephemeral ports are given randomly by the kernel from the range of systctl param - [net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt). My current value is from 32768 to 60999.

Solutions

1. lower the port number for conflicting service.
2. add conflicting port number as reserved (not used by ephemerals) - [ip_local_reserverd_ports](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt)

   ```
   sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports="45455"
   ```
3. change ephemeral port range

   ```
   # my linux default is from 32768 to 60999
   sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="45455 60999"
   ```

Comment: That's ok, but how can one bind that to a specific interface? it binds to 0.0.0.0 by default, which exposes a port to a world. I would comfortable having it listening on internal network only.